# How to use the es6 import statement with runtime bundling using babel standalone?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I understand that runtime bundling in the client side does not have access to the file system so import statements do not work. Does anyone have a solution to this? I can't compile my code via the server side (webpack, gulp, etc..) and it has to be a client side solution. Do I need to build a virtual file system, or are there libraries out there where I can use the import statement in the es6 code that gets transpiled by babel-standalone?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>babel-standalone example</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js">     </script>
  <script type="text/babel">
    import {Hello} from './test.js';
    console.log(Hello);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
//test.js
export default const Hello = 'hello';
```

Comment: You can use SystemJS. *I can't compile my code via the server* - why? This needs explanation because this is how it is usually done.

Comment: My project is to build a text editor in the browser. All the code get's rendered into an iframe (like jsfiddle). However, I want to add tab functionality so that user can create another js file and import it to be used. I can't send that file to the server to be compiled by webpack, then sent back to the client, it would take too long and needs to be called every time the user renders their output in the iframe browser.

Comment: You need to use something for transport then. RequireJS or SystemJS. I'd try the latter.